# Using std::fstream causes program to end with SIGILL in PASE for i (7.3)

Tags: c++, g++, fstream, ibm-midrange

I am working in an IBM i 7.3 environment from IBM's CECC service. I'm attempting to test a large application in the PASE environment, but I've had trouble with scripts that use the `<fstream>` library. Opening a file in write mode causes scripts to terminate with `SIGILL`.

To test this problem, I wrote the following script:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
        std::ofstream writer;

        std::cout << "Writing file.\n" << std::endl;

        writer.open( "out.txt" );
        if ( !writer.is_open() || !writer.good() )
        {
            std::cerr << "Unable to open file." << std::endl;
            return (1);
        }

        writer << "This is a test.\n" << std::endl;

        writer.close();

        return (0);

}
```

Executing the script results in:

```
Writing file.

Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

In GDB:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /storage/persist/[app-directory]/test/log/test_write
[New Thread 1]
Writing file.

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
[Switching to Thread 1]
0x08001000a0027940 in _localeinit.bss_3_ () from /QOpenSys/pkgs/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/6.3.0/../../../libstdc++.so.6(shr_64.o)
(gdb) bt
#0  0x08001000a0027940 in _localeinit.bss_3_ () from /QOpenSys/pkgs/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/6.3.0/../../../libstdc++.so.6(shr_64.o)
```

I ran a quick sanity check on the code by compiling and running it on a CentOS7 dev system, where it runs as expected and returns without errors. I've also copied the code to my home folder, where it creates and writes `out.txt` as expected, but still fails with `SIGILL` rather than returning with no error code. (Running in the application's directory also creates out.txt correctly, but had been failing when `out.txt` had already been created with permissions `-rwx------`).

**Details**

```
g++ --version
g++-6.bin (GCC) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

g++ -dumpmachine
powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0
```

The C++ std library was installed with the following package:

```
libstdcplusplus-devel.ppc64        6.3.0-29                    @ibm
```

The code was compiled with the following command:

```sh
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -g3 -O0 -fpie test_write.cpp -o test_write -lpthread
```

Other programs that do not use `<fstream>` compile and run without errors. I've had trouble finding documentation explaining potential causes for this issue, due to the esoteric nature of the *PASE for i* platform, but I'm expecting it has something to do with the compiler settings. I'd like to figure out what the cause is so that I can make the appropriate changes to my code and/or makefiles to resolve it.

Comment: Make sure to compile/link everything with option `-pthread` otherwise the parts of your programs will be incompatible with each other. (`errno` is a example, check its definition in `errno.h`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using GCC to compile for PASE you must use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread` (or also set `-D_THREAD_SAFE`). Without this you can run in to problems as AIX header files shipped by PASE have compile-time threading behavior. In addition, the libstdc++ has a different ABI depending on whether you compile with `-pthread` or without on AIX platforms. On AIX, GCC will automatically set the binary's runtime library path appropriately to load the pthread or non-pthread GCC libraries while in the open source environment on PASE, we *only* ship the pthread version.